# How to make an ExecutorService create n threads executing exactly same task?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, executor

I am following [this example](https://www.callicoder.com/java-executor-service-and-thread-pool-tutorial/#executorservice-example-with-multiple-threads-and-tasks)

In that example, it is possible to create a pool of threads, which will execute 3 different tasks.

However, I would like to create only one task, that gets executed by n threads.

```java
int numberOfThreads = 2;
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
Runnable task1 = () -> {
  System.out.println("Executing Task1 inside : " + 
  Thread.currentThread().getName());
  try {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
  }
};
executorService.submit(task1, numberOfThreads); // This is not like this obviously
```

How could I achieve this in a propper way?

Comment: Simply submit it multiple times?

Comment: Just submit the same task multiple times, each task will be in a separated thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no magic in it really. All you have to do is submit the same task multiple times like so:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int numberOfThreads = 2;
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numberOfThreads);
    Runnable task1 = () -> {
      System.out.println("Executing Task1 inside : " + 
      Thread.currentThread().getName());
      try {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
      }
    };
    executorService.submit(task1);
    executorService.submit(task1);
}
```

Comment: But then make sure that the task is thread-safe. This one is, as there is no mutable state in it.

Comment: @Thilo well, I'd say it is true for all the multithreaded programs, not only for this one case, so I don't find it necessery to add it here.

Comment: And mind the possibility to use `executorService.invokeAll(Collections.nCopies(numberOfThreads, Executors.callable(task1)));` to submit `numberOfThreads` instances of the task and wait for their completion in one go.